# Search HasMap value for String instance

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap in my GUI class of:

```
HashMap<Integer, Party> partyInput = new HashMap<>();
```

and using a String input from user search the hashMap value for its instance. How do I cast the String to Party Object or Party Object to String? I can search easily the key and have several other programs that search for values of String but can not figure out this scenario. Trying:

```
// target is the value input from user by JTextField
if (partyInput.containsValue(target)) {

    }
```

gives me "Suspicious call to have.util.Map.containsValue: Given object cannot contains instances of String (expected Party)".

Party Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Party extends GameElement{

ArrayList<Creature> creature = new ArrayList<>();

public Party() {
   } // end default constructor

// constructor for all Party member fields
public Party (int index, String name) {
    // get fields from parent GameElement class
    super(index, name);
} // end Party constructor


// getter for creature members of each party
public ArrayList<Creature> getMembers() {
    return creature;
} // end getMemebers method

// setter for creature members of each party
public void setMembers(ArrayList<Creature> partyMembers) {
    this.creature = partyMembers;
} // end setMemebers method

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%n**********************************************************"));
    sb.append(String.format("%nParty: %s%n", getName()));
    sb.append(String.format("Creatures %n"));
    creature.stream().forEach((c) -> {
        sb.append(String.format("**** %s%n", c.getName()));
    });

    return sb.toString();
} // end toString method
} // end Party class
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What property of `Party` does the `target` value correspond to?

Comment: What is `Party`? Are you looking for a particular property of `Party`? It would be easier to help you if you would include a [mcve].

Comment: If `Party` is your own class, you need to work out a way yourself of getting an appropriate `Party` instance of a given string. Or post its code so we have some idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `target` String is the value of some property of `Party`, you need to just iterate the map's values looking for the instance with the matching attribute, e.g.

```
for (Party party : map.values()) {
  if (party.getTarget().equals(target)) {
    // Do whatever.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can construct a `Party` instance from a String then perhaps you could do something along the lines of:

```
if(partyInput.containsValue(new Party(text)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Assuming `equals` has been overridden appropriately.

Or you could iterate over the values set and try to match upon a property in your `Party` object.

```
    for(Party party  : m.values()) {
        if(text.equals(party.getXXX())) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```